# How to let users know flow has completed?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a flow setup in logicapps that starts with a http response, the user enters data in an excel sheet and clicks a cell/hyperlink which kicks things off. They receive a response saying the flow has started and was wondering how I could update the response once the flow has completed (either successfully or if it has failed). I’ve only created basic flows before and when googling I’m not too sure what I should be searching for but cant find any examples of what I’m trying to achieve, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: No, once the response has been sent, that's it.  That's your typical request and response architecture of the internet.  Is there any reason why the response can't be put at the end of the flow?  Otherwise, you'd need to provide something in the response (like an ID or something) that can be polled by the calling application (i.e. an asynchronous style approach) which tells it that it's done and for it to be done, a file with the ID provided then exists in blob storage or something.

Comment: To be honest, I'm still at the stage of following guides/tutorials and cobbling them together so I just put it at the beginning. I didn't think anything of it as at least the user will know the flow has started, depending on how many Teams are created it can take a few seconds or few mins. 
Your suggestion about adding an ID sounds ideal, I'll check for some tutorials on how to do that! Thanks

Comment: I was just thinking, if you’re doing it in Excel then you could change the hyperlink out for a button and in VBA, make the call to the logic app asynchronously. That way, you could change your response to be at the end of the flow and poll the HTTP object for completion. It would mean a lot less orchestration and would get you the result you’re after. It may be out of your direct capability though, not sure.

Comment: I saw a tutorial mentioning something like that. I'll take a look and see if I can work it out. But yeah, probably outwith my skill level just now.
I actually created a few scopes and notified the user via an adaptive card within Teams. Totally different to my original question but at least the user knows if it completed successfully or not.

Comment: Whatever works man!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workarounds that might work. You need to add the response at the end of the flow. Consider my logic app as a sample. If my "Var" is yes then in response it sends `Success` as a response to my postman and if it is other than yes it sends `Failed`. Here is my logic app for your reference:-

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**In postman**

[image]

In your case, you can use some properties to define if they got classes or not and then use the same condition connector to send the response.

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. Skin also suggested putting the response at the end, I just blindly followed a tutorial and it was put at the start. Really appreciate the images/examples, it'll help me work out what I need to do. 
I'll make a copy of the flow and try this out. Thanks!

Comment: SwethaKandikonda-MT, I did this the other day and didnt notice the popup. It says I'm unable to do so:
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."